# Classifying words inside a document

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

The problem that I'm facing is:
I want to read a document, get the raw string of this document, and classify the information.
For example, I want to identify when the string is a "Name", or a "date" ou some other useful information.

Is it possible to use machine learning to do that?
How may I approach the problem?

The most hard problem here is that I'm not trying to classify the document itself, but the String information inside the document.

Comment: Why not? Just consider a String as a short text itself. Check these posts: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118513/algorithm-recommendation-for-string-classification, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79765/improve-precision-in-text-classification.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Vadim. I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's all about how you think about your problem. I think your problem can be formulated as an entity extraction/recognition problem, where you have a document and want to identify specific entities *within* the text (where an entity might be a person, date, etc). Take a look at Conditional Random Fields and their applications to named entity recognition (NER for short), as there are some libraries & tools already implemented.

For example, check out [StanfordNER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml).

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I think this is just what I'm looking for.  My problem seems recurrent, but I didn't know this acronym NER. Thanks.